# Trouble in seeing that if two subsets are conjugates, they are of equal cardinality.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

Suppose $H_1= g \cdot H_2 = gH_2g^{-1}$.

Is there an easy way to see $|H_1|=|H_2|$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $H_1=gH_2$. This means that:

- For each $x\in H_2$, we have $gx\in H_1$, and
- every $y\in H_1$ is of the form $gx$ for some $x\in H_2$.

This means the function $f: H_2\rightarrow H_1: x\mapsto gx$  is surjective. In order to show $H_1$ and $H_2$ have the same cardinality, it would be enough to show that this function is also *injective*.

So: suppose $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$, that is, $gx_1=gx_2$, for some $x_1, x_2\in H_2$. What does that tell you about $x_1$ and $x_2$? (And what property of groups are you using here?)

---

A general rule: whenever you're trying to compare two sets - heck, whenever you mention two sets in the same sentence, even! - always think about whether there are any natural maps between them.

Comment: Thanks. Why do we have a map to $H_2$ though? Isn't it supposed to be $H_1$ or am I mistaken? I can see that $x_1=x_2$ due to cancellation law. @Noah

Comment: also can I say it has the inverse $x \mapsto g^{-1}x$?

Comment: @HenriL For your first question, yes, I had a silly moment - fixed. For your second question, yes, you are quite correct - that's the inverse, and the existence of inverses (or more broadly the cancellation law) is the crucial property you are using.